# MySQL QPS debugging?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I see 5 Kqps on my DB server during 5 mins interval on zabbix dashboard. But sum of all max queries(Delete/select/Insert/Update/Replace) during that interval come out to be 1300.
Not sure how come max 5kqps is displaying but sum of all max is 1300 ? My objective is to find which specific DML(insert/update/select/delete) is causing high QPS here  and get some direction from here ? Another point is to understand is there anything else that can cause high QPS apart from these DML so that I can move in right direction. I am bit confused how come Max QPS can be some of individual DML QPS or I am missing anything here ?

Also IOPS during that shows 1Kops, if each query is is even hitting disk, shouldn't it be close to 5Kops ? Where can be the gap ?

Comment: How are you obtaining these metrics? What would you expect "sum of all max" to be if not 1300, why, and why does that matter?

Comment: What is your goal in this investigation?

Comment: @mustaccio I am getting these metrics from zabbix. My objective is to find which specific DML(insert/update/select/delete) is causing high QPS here  ?

Comment: @danblack updated my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` before and after a test run.  Then look at the differences in `Com_...`, `Questions`, and `Queries`.

Things like `Com_insert` will tell you specifically how many `INSERTs` there were.

If you have Stored routines, `Questions` and `Queries` will not be the same, the difference being due to one counting statements in the routines; the other not.

IOPs may have very little relation to qps.  One `SELECT` could cause millions of IOPs if it is scanning a huge table that is not cached in RAM.  OTOH, a thousand simple `SELECTs` where all the necessary data is cached might cause zero IOPs.

QPS is not as important as the sum of the times for all the queries.  In the previous paragraph, that one big query arguably might have more impact on the system than the thousand small ones.

To find which statements are being naughty, use the slowlog.  It will catch DDLs and DMLs.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: Thanks Rick. I am not using any stored procedures.  Not sure how it can be possibility 5kqps when sum of max  of all other statements are 1300 ?  I understand high QPS is not concern if they are quick one but I see high process list also i.e 1000 which means some queries are slow during that time.   But I see total 5 queries slow during that time . I believe 5 slow queries should not cause 1000 process list considering rest 995 are fast. Isn't it ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Yes, 1000 in `PROCESSLIST` is _some_ concern.  But if most of them are `Sleeping`, then it is not a problem.  How many are not "Sleep"?  A few slow queries _could_ block lots of fast queries -- if they are hitting the same row(s) of the same table(s).  Let's look at the 5; speeding them up won't hurt, and might help.

Comment: @user3198603 more than 100 non-Sleeping processes is a big red flag.  Look for the one that has been running the longest (see "Time").  It _may_ be blocking all the others.

Comment: Sure Rick will optimize the slow one. One follow up question for understanding on `A few slow queries could block lots of fast queries -- if they are hitting the same row(s) of the same table(s)` consider 100 process are trying to execute the queries and five of them are slow.  Even if they are hitting the same row of table, I believe it wont block the other select process and may not slow other. But yes if it update on same rows then first thread will take the lock and block others. Right ?

Comment: @user3198603 - A query that looks through a range of rows will lock all those rows in a small way.  That means that a missing index can lead to more rows than you expect.  "Five are slow" -- Does this mean that the 100 processes are not doing the same thing?  Or what?  In any case, the slowlog is likely to identify the "worst" queries.

Comment: Rick James I have a point regarding sequential disk access methodology. Can a hypothetical statement running for 15 mins which needs to access the disk. Another process need to run for 5 mins say and access the disk. I believe both process will be given the disk access in round robin fashion (considering only thread can access the disk at given point of time) or first one process need to be completed then only second will be given disk access ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Or they are ordered according to which block is "nearest" to the read head (assuming HDD, not SDD).  Or FIFO -- and each thread is providing only one (or a few) requests at a time.  Or...  Bottom line, that level of detail makes it hard to analyze.  And a query that takes even one minute needs to be severely analyzed to see if there is a better way.

Comment: My point is: Will the both threads be given the disk access in round robin fashion like 12.01: T1 executes, 12.02: T2 executes,12.03: T1 executes,.....  like CPU schedules the thread or it will be sequential where T1 will complete all of the operation then only T2 can access the disk ?

Comment: @user3198603 - It in not that easily predictable.  It depends on outside interrupts, the filesystem, the drivers, etc.  Round robin may be a valid approximation in most cases.  I suspect things like `cp` and `dd` have ways to flood the I/O queue.  MySQL will be jumping around a lot, rarely writing more than one 16KB block at a time.  Oh, there is a background task to write "dirty" pages.  There are "syncs or fsyncs" to help with transactional integrity.

Answer (score 2):

As SQL, `show global status like 'com_%'` will show you a break down of the types of queries. Any high volume of update, replace, delete should be an indication that you shouldn't be using MyISAM.

Given there are 5kqps `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` at any instant should give you a sample of activity.

Don't worry about IOPs, focus on the queries and watch the benefits flow from that. If queries are contained to the primary key there is no reason for them to result in disk IOPs. Filesystem cache is also used so that's another buffer preventing IOPs.

If its the IOPs (hardware not handling it) that's the problem consider moving to InnoDB. If you value your data, move to InnoDB.

Comment: I believe in MyISAM DML acquires the table level locks, so even it will block the selects. Right ? So if I move to InnoDB, DML will acquire only row level locks so select can proceed paralely. Right ?

Comment: Selects are not blocked on both MyISAM and Innodb, there is a shared table lock to prevent the table from being modified while a query is run, however multiple threads can acquire this. InnoDB's row based locks is a significant improvement for every operations that manipulates table rows however. Ensure your slow query log is enabled. Row locking depends on indexes and primary keys that map to SQL being used. It will also help queries in general.